# I am getting an error in log but everything works xD. ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'imageUrl') goal: get object by id

Tags: html, angular, spring, typescript

My goal is to display a single book by its ID which I did but there is the error in console.log, even if everything is working

This is the error

```
core.mjs:6485 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'imageUrl')
at BookDetailsComponent_Template (book-details.component.html:11:34)
at executeTemplate (core.mjs:9618:1)
at refreshView (core.mjs:9484:1)
at refreshComponent (core.mjs:10655:1)
at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:9280:1)
at refreshView (core.mjs:9534:1)
at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:10609:1)
at refreshView (core.mjs:9508:1)
at refreshComponent (core.mjs:10655:1)
at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:9280:1)
```

This is the object in console log

```
    Object
author: "Dale Carnegie"
dateCreated: "2022-08-08T18:49:13.000+00:00"
description: "How to Win Friends & Influence People by Dale Carnegie provides readers with strategies on building relationships and dealing with people. Despite being written in the 1930s, the concepts still prove to be applicable today. The 214-page book covers principles ranging from ‘Give honest and sincere appreciation’ to ‘Ask questions instead of giving direct orders.’"
genre: "Self-help book"
id: 8
imageUrl: "assets/images/1/htf.jpg"
name: "How to Win Friends & Influence People"
pages: 288
publishedAt: 1997
quantity: 10
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

The object and the data is displayed on the browser but for some reason I get this error

Here is the method in service class

```
getBook(bookId: number): Observable<Book> {

const bookUrl: string = `${this.baseUrl}/${bookId}`;

return this.httpClient.get<Book>(bookUrl);
}
```

Here is the component class

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { BookService } from './../../services/book.service';
import { Book } from './../../common/book';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-book-details',
  templateUrl: './book-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./book-details.component.css']
 })
export class BookDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

book!: Book;

constructor(private bookService: BookService,
          private route: ActivatedRoute,
          private location: Location          
 ) { }

ngOnInit(): void {

 this.route.paramMap.subscribe(() =>
   this.handleBookDetails()
   );
}


handleBookDetails(): void {
 const bookId: number = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')!;

this.bookService.getBook(bookId).subscribe(
  data => {
    this.book = data;
    console.log(data);
    
  }
)
```

}

This is the HTML part

```
<div class="column is-3-desktop is-3-tablet is-12-mobile">
            <div class="card ">
                <div class="card-image">
                    <figure class="image is-4by5">
                        <img src="{{ book!.imageUrl }}" alt="Placeholder image ">
                    </figure>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because the request is asynchronous and the template renders before the request finishes. When the template renders for the first time the `book` is `undefined` (that's where you get the error). When the request finishes the `book` field is populated (`this.book = data`) and the template re-renders with the new value.

To get rid of the error you can use a [resolver](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) to get the data before component is loaded or show the image only when the value arrives:

```
<img *ngIf="book" src="{{ book.imageUrl }}" alt="Placeholder image ">
```